# Route map are drawn improperly in google maps in javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing a web application and integrated google maps with java script. markers are working fine with good latitude and longitude. the route map is not shown perfectly. when search users in a route map, not showing properly. it shows different routes. it didn't clear previous route. How can I clear previous route? 
[Route Map Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoKJJ.png)

[image]

sample maps code:

```html
 var marker= [];
 var geocoder;
 var map;
 var directionsDisplay,directionsService;
 
   directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ draggable: false, suppressMarkers: true });
   directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
 var request = {
           travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
           
         }; 
      
  googleMapCoordinates(response);
  
  function googleMapCoordinates(response) {
    setMapOnAll(null);
    marker = [];  
          directionsDisplay.setMap(null); 
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(null);   
    $("#map").show();
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 10,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(17.7254567, 83.3097112),
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
       
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: new google.maps.LatLng(response[i].latitude, response[i].longitude),
           map:map,
           label:response[i].count
       }); 
       var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
           return function() {
             infowindow.setContent("Name :"+response[i].name);
             infowindow.open(map, marker);
           }
       })(marker, i));   
          
          /******************Direction*********************************/
          
       if (i == 0) request.origin = marker.getPosition();
       else if (i == response.length - 1) request.destination = marker.getPosition();
          else {
               if (!request.waypoints) request.waypoints = [];
              request.waypoints.push({
                location: marker.getPosition(),
                stopover: true
              }); 
            }
       }
    
     directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
             directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
            }
     });
  }
    
    function setMapOnAll(map) {
      console.log("Set map is to empty state ");
         for (var i = 0; i < marker.length; i++) {
           marker[i].setMap(map);
         }
       }
```